# SoapUI. Add multipart body part using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to add json as multipart body part to "multipart/form-data" request using groovy.

I can do this using file attachments:

```
testRunner.testCase
          .testSteps["/job/result"]
          .getHttpRequest()
          .attachBinaryData(json.toString().getBytes(), "application/json").contentID = "info"
```

My problem is "attachBinaryData" creates a temp file per request. It is not good for load tests :)

Is there other possibility to add body parts, without file attachments?

something like :

```
testRunner.testCase
              .testSteps["/job/result"]
              .getHttpRequest()
              .addBodyPart("application/json", json.toString())
```

P.S. it must be the "add", because request has also one static attachment.

Comment: if you found a solution post it as an answer, it can help somebody else `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution using https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(serviceEndPoint)
def scanResultFile = new File(testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("ScanResultFile"))

http.request( POST ){ req ->

    headers.'Connection' = 'Keep-Alive'
    headers.'User-Agent' = 'SoapUI 4.5.1'
    requestContentType = 'multipart/form-data'

    ByteArrayBody bin = new ByteArrayBody(scanResultFile.readBytes(), "application/octet-stream", "jobResult");
    StringBody info = new StringBody(testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("JsonScanResult"), "application/json", java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity()
    entity.addPart("info", info);
    entity.addPart("jobResult", bin)
    req.entity = entity
}
```

Comment: thank you for posting the solution you found. It is terribly frustrating to be dealt a hand where the tools are only used by those whose exposure to currently popular API frameworks is little to none. It is also really too bad that we have to all too often override built-in SoapUI features (like attachments) because the software is simply incompatible with the peculiarities of the practical world.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `json` to your request as a multipart/form-data using `groovy script` testStep you can use the follow code:

```
def jsonStr = "{'id':'test','someValue':'3'}"

def testStep = context.testCase.testSteps["/job/result"]
// set the content for the request
testStep.getHttpRequest().setRequestContent(jsonStr)
// and set the media type 
testStep.testRequest.setMediaType('application/json')
// if you want to send as a multipart/form-data then use follow line instead
// testStep.testRequest.setMediaType('multipart/form-data')
```

This results in a request configured as follows:

[image]

Hope it helps,

Comment: thank you for replay, I have corrected my question :) It must be a "add" command because request has allready a static body part and with "setRequestContent" it will be overwritten. I mean Request must have two body parts, first one is static (set with gui), second one dynamic (set with groovy)

Comment: @DSmelanskij your static part is also a json? you are looking for a "string concatenation"... like using `testStep.getHttpRequest().requestContent+=jsonStr` instead of `testStep.getHttpRequest().setRequestContent(jsonStr)` or you means a `multipart/form-data` with various elements?

Comment: no, first one is a "octet-stream". Also :
first part:  "application/octet-stream" (static cached file),
second part: "application/json" (dynamic)